# populate radiobuttonlist from database sqlserver and using split() display values each value separetely

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

In my database I have a column named `wing` , in it values are stored like this `A,B,C,D,E`

how i can retrieve value from database into radiobuttonlist separately like below:

```
.A .B .C .D .E
```

here how  can I select any  value like `.D` and `ON BUTTON click` event insert only `.D` in another column?

I have searched a lot on Google but didn't find example like this.

```
private void populatewingname()
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SocietyCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Wing from tblsociety", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if(rdr.Read())
                {
                    string[] words = wing.Split(',');

                    foreach (RadioButtonList item in radiobtn.Items)
                    {
                       // i m confused and dont knw further coding
                    }
                }

                rblwinglist.DataTextField = "Wing";
                rblwinglist.DataSource = rdr;
            }
        }
```

Comment: First off, must you really store your data like that in the DB? That does not comply with normalization rules...

Comment: If you could, I'd suggest you move that wing column to another table where you'd store the information in rows, with a fk to your other table

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking something like:

```
 if(rdr.Read())
                {
                    string[] words = wing.Split(',');
                    int i=0;
                    foreach (RadioButtonList item in radiobtn.Items)
                    {
                       item.Text=word[i]+".";
                       i++;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I agree with this solution, second to normalizing the DB